# every time I run a program on Xcode I get this pop up. its been working for the past few weeks but this issue suddenly occurred

Tags: xcode

[image]screenshot of the pop up saying " The document “stdio.h” could not be saved. You don’t have permission." then under it says "To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info."

Comment: Have you edited stdio.h It is a standard C/Objective-C header so you could have navigated to it in Xcode

Comment: Take a look at [these answers to a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089450/xcode-the-document-could-not-be-saved) and see if they help.

Comment: Is that the `stdio.h` inside your SDK? What's the exact path to that file? (Please redact your username and other sensible information in the path.)